# Как запустить скрипт из bat файла на c++

Tags: c++

Всем добра, есть скрипт из bat файла

```console
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("%AppData%\????????-????-????-????-????????????") do rd "%%~i" /S /Q
```

Как запустить это через код (запуск файла батника из директории не вариант)?
Заранее спасибо

---

Написал такой код, но он не работает

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char cmd[256];
    strcpy(cmd, "@echo off\nfor / d % %i 
    in(\"%AppData%\1C\1Cv8\????????-????-????-????-????????????\") do rd \"%%~i\" / S / Q");
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: См. в сторону `system()`, например.

Comment: суть в том, что через system() не работает, т.к. через system() передаются команды которые можно набрать и запустить в консоли (например, ping или dir), но такой скрипт в консоли не сработает, только через батник запустится

Comment: `for` отлично работает в `system()`. Не забывайте об особенностях применения символа \ в строках С/С++, и все получится :) Кстати, именно вот такое удаление не так уж сложно написать с использованием возможностей `<filesystem>`. Да, вдогонку - уберите ваше `echo off`, оставьте *одну строку* с `for`. Для подавления вывода используйте `@` прямо в команде.

Comment: А если вы вообще уберёте подавление вывода, то по выводу сразу будет понятно, что не так.

Comment: я на плюсах не кодил лет 6 и уже не помню в чем прикол с символом \ в строке, что-то смутно припоминаю, но без конкретики. Напомните пожалуйста

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, у вас в строке есть `\n`. Что здесь означает "\" ? Что следующий символ нужно рассмотреть как особый символ, а собственно сам слеш убрать. То есть при компиляции последовательность из *двух* символов `\n` будет преобразована в *один* символ перевода строки. Слеш в комбинации с другими символами даёт другие результаты. Например, последовательность `\1` вообще будет убрана из строки, так как такой специальной последовательности не существует. Если вы хотите, чтобы после компиляции в строке появился один слеш, то напишите его дважды: "\\".

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, разобрался, заработало!

Answer (score 1):

```
system("@for /d %i in (\"%AppData%\\????????-????-????-????-????????????\") do rd \"%~i\" /S /Q")
```